# How can I use CSS to move 3 of 4 divs from one column into a new column?

Tags: html, css

First, this is the desired effect:

Layout without reordering divs:

[image: Layout]

Layout after reordering divs

[image]

2 is a fixed width. 1,3,4 are all flexable and could be any width.

I have tried using flexboxes, but they will not layout in 2 cols after reordering.

```css
.container { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; width: 700px; }
.d1 {
  order: 2;
  background-color: red;
}
.d2 {
 order: 1;
 background-color: yellow;
 }
 .d3 {
 order: 3;
 background-color: blue;
 }
 .d4 {
 order: 4;
 background-color: green;
 }
 
 .d1,.d2,.d3,.d4 {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  }
  
  .d2 {
   height: 200px;
   }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="d1">1</div>
  <div class="d2">2</div>
  <div class="d3">3</div>
  <div class="d4">4</div>
 </div>
```

I have also tried float 2 to the left, but it does not make 1, 3 and 4 take up all of rest of the avaible space of the container. (it needs to do so at any container width)

```css
.container { position: relative; width: 900px; border: 1px solid black; }
.d1 {
float: right;
  background-color: red;
}
.d2 {
 float: left;
 background-color: yellow;
 }
 .d3 {
 float: right;
 background-color: blue;
 }
 .d4 {
 float: right;
 background-color: green;
 }
 
 .d1,.d2,.d3,.d4 {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  }
  
  .d2 {
   height: 200px;
   }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="d1">1</div>
  <div class="d2">2</div>
  <div class="d3">3</div>
  <div class="d4">4</div>
 </div>
```

**I forgot to mention that all of this is inside another container that needs to have the height its contents**

Comment: relevant code has been added.

Comment: I forgot to mention that all of this is inside another container that needs to have the height its contents

Comment: A thought: if the outer container could know the height of div 2 (which is variable - not the width) it could be set to a height of div2. Then i could use flex-direction: column, and the remaining divs would wrap to the second col.

Comment: codepen.io/anon/pen/RyPONr
something like that. where the height of #2 is variable. My attempt to assign number 2 different heights in the css have failed, something is holding them to the same thing, but you see what i'm trying to do here. I need to get to bed. I will check this out tomorrow Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### **Outer Container**(Requirement)

**Total Height** should be less than Height of `1st div` and `2nd div`.

*Reason: So `flex-wrap` will provide the desired output*

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  height: 60vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.two {
  width: calc(100vw - 400px);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  height: 16vh;
  background: red;
}

.one {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 50vh;
  color: white;
  height: 50vh;
  background: green;
}

.three {
  width: calc(100vw - 400px);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 20vh;
  color: white;
  height: 20vh;
  background: orange;
}

.four {
  width: calc(100vw - 400px);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  height: 23vh;
  background: black;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 601px) {
  .outer {
    height: 150vh;
  }
  .one {
    order: 2;
    width: 100vw;
  }
  .two {
    order: 1;
    width: 100vw;
  }
  .three {
    order: 3;
    width: 100vw;
  }
  .four {
    order: 4;
    width: 100vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="one">2</div>
  <div class="two">1</div>
  <div class="three">3</div>
  <div class="four">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: div 2 is a fixed width div of 400px. div 1,2,4 have no fixed width and must expand to fill the available space at any container size.

Comment: Updated, please check.

Comment: does the outer container need a specified height? In my actual use, this snippet will appear multiple times on the site, each in its own container. The containers height needs to auto-size to the height of its content.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is what you want - as outlined in your question:

- 2 column layout
- `.d2` is fixed width
- others take up remainder of available space

It's certainly possible using a number of approaches but flexbox works as good as any.  Just take `.d2` out of the regular flow by giving it absolute positioning.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.d1,
.d3,
.d4 {
  margin-left: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.d1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.d2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
}

.d3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.d4 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="d1">1</div>
  <div class="d2">2</div>
  <div class="d3">3</div>
  <div class="d4">4</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

Since additional criteria has been offered in comments below here's another solution that does not rely on absolute positioning and keeps `.d2` in the flow of things.  In this type of layout your fixed-width for `.d2` is specified in the 1st column definition of the grid:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto;
}

.d1,
.d3,
.d4 {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

.d1 {
  background-color: red;
  
}

.d2 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 4;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 150px;
}

.d3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.d4 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="d1">1</div>
  <div class="d2">2</div>
  <div class="d3">3</div>
  <div class="d4">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even this approach is great. +1 Got to learn something new :)

Comment: @DhavalJardosh - thanks.  frankly i'm still trying to grasp what you've done in your solution to make this work.  just a bit more explanation in your answer would be great.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out what I did wrong in my above css. My "right cols" are not stacking, only div 1 ends up on the right.

Comment: Ok it's the absolution positioning of div2. Problem is all of this is inside of another container (repeated many times) that needs it's height push open to the height of at least div2. Taking it out of positioning removes that. I'll have to look at @DhavalJardosh approach. Would have rather used yours as it's simpler.

Comment: @danjfoley - this question is like a moving target.  you keep adding requirements and criteria that aren't mentioned at first.  it's a bit difficult to provide a working solution and unfair to answerers when you do that.

Comment: agreed, I just thought it would be way to much code to post. Sorry about that.

Comment: it would be encouraging if you at least gave an upvote all the existing answers which work according to the criteria you provided. At any, here's another possibility.  Hopefully this works for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169482/discussion-between-danjfoley-and-billynoah).

Answer (score 3):

Not perfect but you can start from here.  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcwjLjbc/6/)

```css
.flex div {
  padding:1em;
  width:100%;
  left:400px;
  box-sizing:border-box; 
}

.flex {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

#div-1 {background:red;float:right; }
#div-2 { min-height: 300px; order: 1; background:yellow;}
#div-3 { order: 3; background:lime;}
#div-4 { order: 4; background:skyblue;}

@media (min-width:500px) {
  .flex { flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap;}
  #div-1 { order: 2; width:calc(100% - 400px); height: 100px }
  #div-2 { width: 400px; }
  #div-3 { width:calc(100% - 400px); position: absolute; top: 100px; right: 0;height:100px; }
  #div-4 { width:calc(100% - 400px); position: absolute; top: 200px; right: 0;height:100px; }  
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div id="div-1">1</div>
  <div id="div-2">2</div>
  <div id="div-3">3</div>
  <div id="div-4">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't mention it until the last edit, but 2 is the only fixed width div. 1,3 and 4 can be of any width. The idea is to be able to have the parent container be any width and 1,3 and 4 still stretch out to fill up the remaining space. Make div 2 exactly 400px. then you can't use a percentage for the others.